# Insect identification, what is this thing?

Tags: identification, insects

Here is a picture of a bug, I found on my plant does anyone know what it is?[image: insect in small bag, highlighted in red]

Comment: How about giving us a closeup?  And what plant was it found on?

Comment: Which plant, as already asked, and what symptoms are you seeing on the plant?

Comment: What kind of soil are you using?  Garden soil?  Could be fly larva but really need more information to answer Grahams and Bamboo's question.  Next pic, use a penny in your picture.  Picture of your plant, in its pot and environment, type of soil (hope it is not garden soil), how you water...anything you can think to add, nothing is too small!